# Why does my jQuery $.each() function return 4 objects, when there should only be one?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a button that does an ajax call to this page:  http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. When I'm not using `$.each()`, it displays one post. But if I use `$.each()`, it returns 4 objects. See screen shot:

[image: result of ajax call]

Here is the jQuery:

```
button.on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
        method  : 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success : function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            /* Build HTML result */
            $.each(result, function(index, post){
                var msg = $('<p></p>');
                    msg.append('Title: '+result.title+'<br>');
                    msg.append('User ID: '+result.id+'<br>');
                    msg.append(result.body);
                    msg.insertAfter(button);
            });
        },
        error   : function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
            alert('Error ' + errorType + ' with message:' + errorMessage);
        },
        timeout : 3000,
        beforeSend : function() {
            //runs before request is send
            smiley.remove();
            confirmation.insertBefore(button);
        },
        complete: function() {
            //runs once the request is finished
            confirmation.remove();
            smiley.insertBefore(button);
        }
    });
});
```

But according to jsonplaceholder, there should only be one object. Also, my console says there should only be one object.

Here is the JSON I get back:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Why do `$.each()` output the same result 4 times? And how do I fix it, so it only output it once?

**EDIT: What I learned from the answers below**

Thanks for all the help & tough, but good love. I now understand that depending on what is returned (object, array, html, json), I need different ways of processing the result.

In the above case the following code was sufficient (thanks @user1278584):

```
var msg = 'Title: '+result.title+'<br>';
msg += 'User ID: '+result.id+'<br>';
msg += result.body;
$("<p>" + msg + "</p>").insertAfter(button);
```

I hope this helps other beginning programmers. Cheers to you all.

Comment: You're asking about the result of parsing JSON. So: Post the JSON. Don't link to it, and certainly don't show screenshots of it.

Comment: Makes sense.. you have 4 objects in your `results`: `body`, `id`, `title` and `userId`.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. I'm green at programming, and really green with jquery. I have also updated the question to show json. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.each` method iterates all object properties if given argument is object instead of array, you shouldn't be using `$.each` or should wrap returned objects into array.

Answer (score 2):

It's not returning "4 objects".

Visit http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 in your browser.

It's an object with 4 properties. You're iterating over the properties. Consult the jQuery docs for proper `$.each` usage.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayns4Lxr/

As other have mentioned, your JSON response has four objects, so that's why you are getting 4 results.

If you want to change your JSON results to use the `$.each` property, then change your response to something like this:

```
{
    "results": {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer. You wouldn't happen to know how I can change a response, when I am not creating the response myself? Sorry if this is a 'doh' question ;)